# empty event listener: Is this ok?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile, button

**Some Quick Background**

I'm building an iOS app that uses html web views in some areas. I wanted to make sure the html buttons on those pages looked and felt as much like iOS buttons as possible. To accomplish this, I wanted a tap state so the html button depressed when tapped. Now in HTML this is easy. You just set a style for :active or :hover or whatever. I actually had this defined already. In iOS, however, those states don't engage on tap – at least normally. So my goal was to write a little script that added a class to the button to change its appearance ontouchstart.

**The Issue**

However, it turns out I didn't need to get that complicated...by pure accident I ran a test with the following code:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
    console.log("test");
}, true);
```

I'm pretty green with javascript & jQuery, so all I intended on doing was checking my syntax and making sure the eventListener fired when I tapped the button.  To my surprise, the button's :active states in the css fired (as well as the :hover states).  That code...solved my problem!

**My Question**

So here's my question:  Is the above code valid?  I mean, is it bad to do this?  It's as if the empty eventListener just triggered behavior that desktop browsers already offer.  Is there anything wrong with using this method?  I'm green, but I don't want to pick up bad habits.  If this is a bad way to code I don't want to use it.

Thanks for any insight you guys can give me into this!

Comment: you can have empty event listeners if you want but I think console.log() will give a js error in IE

Comment: There's nothing wrong with empty listeners. But every listener you have adds that tiny bit of overhead that you probably shouldn't care about. It's important to check for `console` and `console.log` because they may not be available unless a debugging console is open (like Firebug or Developer Tools) - not based on browser.

Comment: I'm all about keeping code lean and mean.  For the purposes of this post I left the console.log command in the code to illustrate my original intent.  Afterwards, I did remove it and simply left the event listener completely empty.

Comment: Are you sure they didn't work without the listener? It sounds to me like changing the script happened to refresh the cache.

Comment: Yes I'm positive.  I removed the listener and they once again stopped displaying the :active :hover states.  I have absolutely no idea why adding an empty listener triggers mobile safari's ability to display :active :hover states, but it appears to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't think anything's wrong with empty event listeners (save for the overhead of a function call --- which sounds negligible here anyway). I'd suggest you leverage jQuery's `noop` function though if you *must* add an event listener but have it do nothing:

```
$(document).on('touchstart', $.noop);

// or

document.addEventListener('touchstart', $.noop);
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the benefit of this is?  I'm not familiar with noop.  ...and thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I googled noop and came up with this "You can use this empty function when you wish to pass around a function that will do nothing.

This is useful for plugin authors who offer optional callbacks; in the case that no callback is given, something like jQuery.noop could execute."

However, I'm wondering what the benefit of this is?  Is it purely to distinguish between codebits that do something and those that do not?

Comment: It's basically an already-made empty function. Instead of "instantiating" your own, use one already ready for use! :D The text you're quoting describes how it can be used in a more complex manner, like if you *must absolutely no-questions-asked* call a function, but you're not sure whether or not you'll have an actual function to call, you can fall back to calling `$.noop()`.